# NSString convertation from Windows-1251 to Windows-1252

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encoding, character-encoding

I have NSString with "ÀÔÐÎÍÖÅÂ ÔÅÄ" text.
I know that this text in Windows-1251 Encoding.

I want to convert it to Windows-1252 and show to user.

I try something like this, but its rise system exception:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What exception is thrown exactly? Did you convert your NSString first into NSData using the encoding?

Comment: @Larme thank you for question. i use wrong approach. i write answer below.

Comment: @DanilShaykhutdinov How are you getting the string initially? There's a more efficient and direct solution than the one you have below.

Comment: @ItaiFerber after qr-code scan I receive this string value

Comment: @DanilShaykhutdinov So you get it from an `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`'s `stringValue`, correct?

Comment: @ItaiFerber maybe, I use ZXing open source library (obj-c port) and it return only value. - (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result {     if (result) {         NSString *formatString = [self barcodeFormatToString:result.barcodeFormat];         NSLog(@"Scanned!\n\nFormat: %@\n\nContents:\n%@", formatString, result.text); } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it works.

solution is:

```
var dt = new NSString(str);
var data = dt.Encode(NSStringEncoding.WindowsCP1252, true);
var result = new NSString(data, NSStringEncoding.WindowsCP1251);
```